# Grafana label filter by metric results

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Hi I would like to create a label filter for my labels that are based on the result of the metric.

Currently, what I have is something like this:

```
label_values(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{subscriptionID=~"$sub"}, resourceName)
```

But I want to filter it based on the healthy/unhealthy resources

```
label_values(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{subscriptionID=~"$sub"}==0, resourceName)
```

or

```
label_values(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{subscriptionID=~"$sub"}==1, resourceName)
```

To make it more dynamic the idea is to have it as a variable:

```
label_values(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{subscriptionID=~"$sub"}==$status, resourceName)
```

But when I try this, it is not working even if I put the value at 0 or 1. I can only filter it based on the values of the attribute.

I also tried to check if there is a way to filter it this way

```
label_values(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{subscriptionID=~"$sub", value=="0"}, resourceName)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official Grafana's [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#use-interval-and-range-variables) says:

> The `label_values` function doesn’t support queries, so you can use these variables in conjunction with the `query_result` function to filter variable queries.

For example of query you mentioned in your question you'll need the following:

```
Query: query_result(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{subscriptionID=~"$sub"} == $status)
Regex: /resourceName="([^"]+)"/
```

Explanation of reges:

Result of the query would look somthing like

```
query_result(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{subscriptionID="aeaeaeae-e23e-23e2-32e23e", instance="myinstance.azure.net:8455", resource Name="my-resource"}
```

You need to extract `my-resource` from it. For this regex matching `resource Name="my-resource"` is used, and desired outcome is captured into the group. Grafana the automatically exctracts this group into output.

- `/` denotes start and end of the regex,
- `resourceName="` and `"` match exactly that.
- `([^"]+)` matches any symbol except quote, and captures it into the group.

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick! Can you explain how you were able to build the regex for the resource name?

Comment: @eojilaJA, added explanation to answer.