# Is it possible to create a variable in grafana that is a combination of a constant and a query?

Tags: grafana, promql

I am trying to create a variable that holds values both for a query and for a constant.

I created a new variable names "hostname" where I want it to hold the values of the following query:

```
label_values(up{site=~"$site",env=~"$env",team=~"$team",service=~"$service",hostname!~".*exporter"}, hostname)
```

and also hold the following constant values: alpha1, alpha2, alpha3.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy built in way to do this.

But you can make your query return additional metrics like this:

```
up{site=~"$site",env=~"$env",team=~"$team",service=~"$service",hostname!~".*exporter"}
or absent(non_existent{hostname="alpha1"})
or absent(non_existent{hostname="alpha2"})
or absent(non_existent{hostname="alpha3"})
```

Since this is not simple selector, you cannot use `label_values` here, you need to use `query_result` and regex extractor.

Your query will be

```
query_result(
 up{site=~"$site",env=~"$env",team=~"$team",service=~"$service",hostname!~".*exporter"}
 or absent(non_existent{hostname="alpha1"})
 or absent(non_existent{hostname="alpha2"})
 or absent(non_existent{hostname="alpha3"})
)
```

And regex `/hostname="([^"]+)"/`

More details about `query_result` and why it must be used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095149/21363224).