# In Grafana a variable that displays only pods that were up in the last 10 minutes

Tags: kubernetes, jvm, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

In Grafana I am using this query to get the list of pods that are relevant

```
label_values(kube_pod_info{environment=~"$environment", pod=~"$deployment.+"}, pod)
```

This returns a list of pods. How can I alter this query to display only the pods that were up in the past 10 minutes (or any other $pods_up_interval)?

I tried to add `[10m]` right after the query:

```
kube_pod_info{environment=~"$environment", pod=~"$deployment.+"}[10m]
```

but that did not work.

I am expecting to see a reduced list of pods. Only those that were up at around that time.

This is useful because typically when debugging or checking on the health of the system its useful to see the pods that are actually alive.

Comment: What is your problem? Does your current attempt show too many, or not enough pods?

Comment: What I have right now shows too many pods. Some pods if I chose then show empty graphs or partial graphs. I want to show only pods that are currently running. Furthermore the second code block is what I attempted which does not work.

Comment: Can you check if something like [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/243#issuecomment-325585227) might help you? It seems like `kube_pod_info` exposes data for more then just active pods, and it requires some filtering. (I recommend checking those queries in Explorer page or on Prometheus itself, as this is not a trivial vector selector, and [you'll need to change approach for parameter definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095149/21363224))

Comment: @markalex yes I was thinking about something like that. For some reason Grafana does not recognized `AND` so that when I write this type of query inside `label_values(..., pod)` I get an error about how I can use just the one metric query but I cannot combine with `AND` etc.

Comment: This is another problem. `label_values` indeed only supports vector selectors. You should [use `query_result` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095149/21363224)

Comment: @markalex thanks very much for the effort. But this has become way to awkward and a time blackhole. I am moving on and my team will just have to click through the drop down menu of pods to see the ones that are up.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentations looks like kube_pod_info is a gauge. Im assuming it returns a 0 or nothing if its down and a 1 if its up -Please clarify me this- so a simple:

```
kube_pod_info{environment=~"$environment", pod=~"$deployment.+"}>0
```

will only return the pods that are working.

If that metric is not a time range you cant use the "[10m]" Instead use the default time ranges

Comment: Notice that this is being used for a `label_values()` in the following way:
`label_values(kube_pod_info{...}, pod)`

I may be using it wrong but this works very well for the dashboard drop down menu for `$pod`.

Maybe I should use a different input query for `label_values()` for this purpose.

The idea is to have a dropdown menu that will determine what `$pod` is for the panels.