How to use group_left join query inside grafana variable query
I have two metrics like as below:
weblogic_id{domain="name", instance="instance"}
weblogic_jvm_uptime{instance="instance", server="serverName"}
what I am trying to achieve is getting the server value using the domain value from weblogic_id metric.
so I try to use the below query in grafana query tab:
label_values(weblogic_jvm_uptime + on (instance) group_left(domain) weblogic_id{domain="domain_name"}, server)
but it's not allowing me to use group_left inside grafana query tab. Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks.

This is probably because label_values accepts only simple metric selector. To get labels from results of complex queries like here, you'll need to use regex.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095149/21363224
